# Why can't a PowerShell function return a MessageQueue object?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I've written the following variations of a function to return a `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` object:

```
set-strictmode -version latest
add-type -AssemblyName System.Messaging
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'

function Get-MsmqQueue1 {
    New-Object "Messaging.MessageQueue" -Args '.\private$\barneytest'
}

function Get-MsmqQueue2 {
    $q = New-Object "Messaging.MessageQueue" -Args '.\private$\barneytest'
    $q
}

function Get-MsmqQueue3 {
    $q = New-Object "Messaging.MessageQueue" -Args '.\private$\barneytest'
    Write-Output $q
}

function Get-MsmqQueue3a {
    $q = New-Object "Messaging.MessageQueue" -Args '.\private$\barneytest'
    if ($q) {
        Write-Debug "Successfully created $($q.QueueName)"
    } else {
        Write-Error "No queue object created"
    }
    Write-Output $q
}

$q = Get-MsmqQueue3a
$q
if ($q) {
    Write-Debug $q.QueueName
} else {
    Write-Error "No queue object returned"
}
```

None of them return an object. It's somehow being swallowed up by PowerShell. Note that the "3a" version has logging to prove that the value it's writing to the pipeline is *not null*, yet *no value is returned from the function*.

How can this be? Is this a PowerShell bug?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: 3 and 3a will not work for sure. Write-Output prints the object to the screen and does not return anything. 1 or 2 should both work, but I can't test them myself because I don't have Message Queuing installed

Comment: Sorry mate, I believe you're confusing it with `Write-Host`. "Write-Output sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline. If the command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in the console." Taken from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx

Comment: I learn something new everyday. Thanks

Comment: No problem. The reason `Write-Output` "appears" to do the same thing as `Write-Host` is because it takes items from the pipeline, and writes them to the pipeline. In PowerShell, when items fall out of the end of the pipeline, they are written to the console. Basically there's a kind of implicit `Write-Host` at the end. That might vary by host implementation, but the OOTB one behaves that way.

Comment: So, if you had `Write-Output` as the last command in the pipeline, you may as well leave it off and it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an idiot. It's not a bug, but it's interesting. Because `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` by enumerating it's messages, the behaviour I was seeing was that PowerShell was actually reading the messages off the newly-created queues and putting them into the pipeline rather than the queue objects themselves. Of course because the queues were new, they were empty, so there was nothing passed on down the pipeline.

I just spent most of this afternoon and some hours this evening working this out. I am not proud of myself.