# How to return an IEnumerable without enumerating it?

Tags: powershell

I wasted a good afternoon struggling with this problem and I came up with two test cases that yield seemingly contradictory results:

```
function enumerateQueueExample() {
    $x = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue '.\private$\myQueue';
    return $x;
}
```

and

```
function dontEnumerateQueueExample() {
    return New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue '.\private$\myQueue';
}
```

So then, assuming this queue exists and is empty, calling `enumerateQueueExample()` returns nothing (e.g. `$x = enumerateQueueExample; $x -eq $null;`) returns `$true`.

On the other hand calling `dontEnumerateQueueExample()` returns the message queue object which is what I really wanted (e.g. `$x = enumerateQueueExample; $x -eq $null;`) returns `$false` and you have a valid message queue in `$x` at the end.

You can't nest this behaviour so the following function will also lead to enumerating the queue:

```
function nestedCall() { 
    return (dontEnumerateQueueExample);
}
```

So my question is how I can workaround this behaviour (we can either call it a feature, or a design flaw depending on how you use it) so that my function (either `nestedCall()` or `enumerateQueueExample()`) actually returns a messageQueue instead of enumerating it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950141/why-cant-a-powershell-function-return-a-messagequeue-object) further covers the behaviour.

Comment: `return dontEnumerateQueueExample;` or `return ,(dontEnumerateQueueExample);`